# How to extract sub-strings based on indices

Tags: python, string, indices

My goal is to extract from the string below, sub-strings that covers the range of each given indices.

```
_string='the old school teacher is having a nice time at school'
index_list=[[0,1,2],[4,7,20]]
```

My attempt:

```
1)>>> [[[_string[y] for y in x]for x in index_list]
[['t', 'h', 'e'], ['o', ' ', 'e']]

2)>>>[_string[x[0:]] for x in index_list]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not list
```

The first attempt extracted only the characters that corresponded with the indices, while the second resulted in `TypeError`.

Desired output:

```
['the', 'old school teach']
```

Any suggestions on how to arrive at the desired output? thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the format of your index lists?

Comment: It seems to me that your second indexes of your index_list items are useless since the desired output your are describing seems to be based just on the first and last index of each entry. Am I right?

Comment: Even if it is the first and last index, the output isn't consistent. Perhaps the second item in the list should be [4, 21]?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo  [0:2] and [4:20] does not give the desired output.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo, you are absolutely right. Its just the range that matters.

Comment: Do you will extract complete words always o chars too?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik, you are right about the output. I'll edit now.

Comment: @Tiger1 Your are wellcome! But it isn't necessary to thank answers, that is the site's purpose ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are delimiting each selection using just the first and last indexes of each selector:

```
[ _string[x[0]:x[-1]] for x in index_list]
```

If your last index is inclusive, you should at 1 to the right limit:

```
[ _string[x[0]:(x[-1]+1)] for x in index_list]
```

Comment: @M4rtini I don't know if the last character is inclussive for him, I'll edit my answer to describe that case.

Answer (score 2):

```
_string='the old school teacher is having a nice time at school'
index_list=[[0,1,2],[4,7,20]]
print [_string[x[0]:x[-1]+1] for x in index_list]
```

Is it what you are looking for?
You only need the first (x[0]) and the last (x[-1]) indexes.
Maybe you'll have to change 20 to 21 if you want the whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just the range that matters, then you can do this:

```
>>> _string='the old school teacher is having a nice time at school'
>>> index_list=[[0,1,2],[4,7,20]]
>>> [_string[i[0]:i[-1]+1] for i in index_list]
['the', 'old school teache']
```

So, you should change the index list to `[[0,1,2],[4,7,21]]`. And if it is just the first and last item you care about, perhaps you can get rid of the middle element altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in a different approach.
First, if I understand correctly your problem, you only need the first and the last index of your list(if it is sorted). So you can try and remove the other values:

```
second_index = [[x[0],x[-1]] for x in index_list]
```

and then you can produce your output like that:

```
[_string[x[0]:x[1]+1] for x in second_index]
```